# Nonlinear Regression in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-fitting, non-linear-regression

I am trying to solve a nonlinear regression problem. Basically, I have a set of Data given as Cure, Cure rate and Temperature (all in vertical column vector). I have also got a function where when I input initial parameters guess in it.

I tried to used

```
x = lsqcurvefit(@model_fun,x0,Cure,Cure rate)
```

and it will give me the parameters that I want. So my question is, are there other methods that I can use for this case? I want to compare how well are the methods could do in fitting.

- I have also tried nlinfit and looked into other methods, such as polyfit, robustfit, fminunc, fit, etc

But they are either not using my data or the model function  which is not useful in my case

Thank you for your reading guys , really need a help

Comment: Have you worked through [this](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinear-regression-1.html)? Can you include your exact code on how you called `nlinfit` and what didn't work?

Comment: Hi hbaderts, 
nlinfit is fine but I am looking for more methods and compare their R^2 value and see which method is better

Comment: Moreover, I have tried fitnlm and lsqnonlin but they dont work. But ppl are saying they are same as nlinfit and lsqcurvefit cause the equations they used inside

Comment: You can try different model functions. `nlinfit` and `lsqcurvefit` both use least squares to fit your model function to the data, so they should give the same coefficients. However, by using different model functions and comparing their (adjusted) R^2 value, you can find out which model function describes your data best.

Comment: If you type `optimtool` then the GUI for optimisation appears. Then you can try the different algorithms.

Comment: @hbaderts Even though both use least-square this does not ensure the same coefficient as the function is nonlinear - that depends on the minimisation algorithm.

Comment: Just to add to the conversation: least squares fit is not a method. Its a minimization proposition. You can solve a least squares problem with multiple methods. MATLABs `lsqcirvefit` uses multiple methods to do this, depending on the constrains and other stuff.

Comment: Thank you guys!!! Lots of helps, I am now trying to get the R2 value from the result of nlinfit and lsqcurvefit. Plus I am looking on optimtool, hope it will works

Comment: There are various methods for fitting directly available with base matlab. The problem is that your question is about fitting specific data. Not programming. Whatever method you use, you need to have underlying motivations. And that's not programming. I would show samples of your data and ask the question on other stackexchange sites.